# Регулярная генерация статистики на основе последних данных

Tags: mongodb hadoop mysql

Есть следующая задача, имеется набор данных в `MongoDB` которые туда постоянно пишутся, необходимо регулярно генерировать статистику на основе последних данных, а результат обновлять в `MySQL`. Сейчас генерация статистики и обновление данных в `MySQL` выполняется `php` скриптом, но это занимает много времени, поэтому решил использовать `hadoop` для генерации.

Получается следующая схема: последние актуальные данные читаются хадупом с `MongoDB`, там они обрабатываются, и после обработки необходимо обновить старые данные в `MySQL`, но это сотни миллионов строк в базе.

Как в данном случае лучше всего перенести эти данные в `MySQL`? Пока думаю над следующими вариантами, вставлять с `reduce` функции данные сразу в `MySQL` (но это будет очень медленно), или сохранять результат в файлы в `hdfs` и потом читать их отдельным скриптом и вставлять блочно в `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скажу из своего опыта работы с Hadoop: если он будет бежать на одной машине, то быстрее не получится. Hadoop имеет смысл использовать с кластерами, т.е. когда можно запустить процесс обработки больших количеств данных сразу на нескольких машинах. Это первое.

Второе, имеет смысл результаты обработки сразу записывать в базу данных, а не записывать в отдельный файл, а потом снова читать этот файл. Это замедлит процесс, если только, разумеется, сам процесс обработки не подразумевает многоступенчатый map-reduce.